# Filtrar un objeto multidimensional dinámico

Tags: javascript, objeto, filtro

por más que busco no encuentro la referencia, tengo un objeto que contiene elementos y a la vez otros objetos -se requiere filtrar el objeto de acuerdo a los parámetros establecidos dinámicamente y para hacerlo utilizo la función filter sin embargo no filtra en los objetos anidados y no es dinámico

```
{
   avg: "650.0000000",
   cantidad: "1",
   id_marca: "1",
   id_modelo: "1282",
   id_moneda: "1",
   id_producto: "100085",
   nombre_marca: "Hp",
   nombre_modelo: "15-cs3003ca",
   nombre_subcategoria: "Laptops",
   especificacion:
   {
      cod_cualidad: "301001",
      cod_esp: "201002",
      cod_productodetalle: "501638",
      cualidad: "Procesador",
      tipocualidad: "Procesador",
   }
}
```

Este es el procedimiento que realice sin embargo al filtrar cualidad no lo realiza

```
const marcas    = ["Dell", "Hp", "Lenovo"];
const modelos   = ["LAPTOP", "Pavilion", "Envy", "Vostro"];
const cualidad  = ["301001", "301002"]

const filtered = productos.filter((item)=>{
        return marcas.includes(item.nombre_marca) 
            && modelos.includes(item.nombre_linea)
            && cualidad.includes(item.cod_cualidad)
});

    console.warn(filtered)
```

Comment: Para referirte a los objetos anidados debes respetar la estructura de un producto. Algo como `cualidad.includes(item.especificacion.cod_cualidad)`. Por otro lado, quizá debas sustituir los `&&` por los `||`, aunque no es necesario. Tampoco veo ninguna propiedad llamada `nombre_linea` en tu objeto.

Comment: Nota que si usas `&&`  las tres condiciones deben cumplirse para que se seleccione un producto, y el producto que adjuntas no coincide con ningún modelo del array modelos, por tanto, no será matcheado.